# How to get value from dict if its key can have several values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a dict with credentials like the following:

```
secret = {"password": "jdksal",
          "user": "fjdklas",
          "schema": "jfdaskl"}
```

I want to create a variable for password, user and schema. However, the secret dict can have other values for each key, so that I would have a list of possibles ways of naming the elements, like the following:

```
pass_words = ['password', 'pass', 'contraseña']
```

Thus, the variable password would be created when any key of the list `pass_words` exists in the dictionary. Only one word from pass_words would be present in the dict. Same with user, schema etc. So far I have this code:

```
for word in pass_words:
    if word in secret:
        password = secret[word]

user_words = ['user', 'username', 'login', 'name']
for word in user_words:
     if word in secret:
         user = secret[word]
```

It works, but its very verbose. Is there any less verbose way to do it? Thanks

Comment: There will only be one word in `pass_words` in `secret` or potentially more than one?

Comment: .Just one word.

Comment: If you have to do this multiple times, I suggest creating a class to implement this functionality or a function for quick lookup. I've done this before by implementing a function and it worked well for me. The only thing I highly recommend is to store your "likely words" in a set instead of a list since lookup time will be O(1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have written it, `password` will get the last match if there is more than one overlap between `pass_word` and `secret`. I don't know is that is your intent.

You could use set operations if there is only one overlap:

```
>>> secret.keys() & pass_words
{'password'}
>>> secret.keys() & user_words
{'user'}
```

Then to get the value associated with that key:

```
>>> secret[(secret.keys() & pass_words).pop()]
jdksal
>>> secret[(secret.keys() & user_words).pop()]
fjdklas
```

For older Pythons that don't have dict set views, just apply `set` to each for the same result:

```
>>> set(secret.keys()) & set(user_words)
{'user'}
```

---

With Python 3.6+, you can do:

```
password, user={k:v for k,v in secret.items() if k in pass_words+user_words}.values()
```

Comment: Thanks! That is only half of the issue though. Once I know that 'password' and 'user' are the existing keys, I need to get the value from the dict. Is there any better way than secret[list(secret.keys() & pass_words)[0]] ?

Comment: @JavierLópezTomás: `secret[(secret.keys() & pass_words).pop()]`

Answer (score -2):

I Think This Will Be Better:

```py
pass_words = ['password', 'pass', 'contraseña']

secret = {"password": pass_words,
          "user": "fjdklas",
          "schema": "jfdaskl"}

input_password = input("Enter Your Password: ")
for key,value in secret.items():
    if input_password in value:
        print("Correct Password")
```

You Can Change The Input Method As You Like. The *Key* Variable Will Hold The Key Of The First Item In The Dictionary And The *Value* Variable Will Hold The Value, Which Will Be A List In Your Case, For The First Item In The Dictionary.