# Why am I getting dict_values instead of str?

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have the following initial variables:

```
secret = {"password": "jdksal",
          "user": "fjdklas",
          "schema": "jfdaskl"}
pass_words = ['password', 'pass', 'contraseña']
user_words = ['user', 'login', 'username']
```

I want to assign variables if the secret dict contains a key that are in any of the lists. So I would run this command (obtained from [How to get value from dict if its key can have several values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66460775/how-to-get-value-from-dict-if-its-key-can-have-several-values)):

```
password, user={k:v for k,v in secret.items() if k in pass_words+user_words}.values()
```

It works perfectly and I get both `password` and `user` as strings. However, if I do the same for just one variable like:

```
password ={k:v for k,v in secret.items() if k in pass_words}.values()
```

I get `password` as type `dict_values`. Why is that?

Comment: Because `.values()` called on a dict returns `dict_values`. Why do you expect a string?

Comment: The return type of `.values()` doesn't change, but you've changed how you're storing it.

Comment: Your first use of `password, user = ...` seems overly convoluted; I'm not really sure what you are trying to do there, but it's definitely unclear, and should be done simpler. Once done that, your actual problem may also be solved.

Comment: @00 Thanks for answering You can get more detailed info on what I am trying to achieve in the linked question. If `.values()` returns `dict_values` why am I getting strings then?

Comment: You're not getting strings: you're getting `dict_values`. Which you can unpack, which is what you do in the first example: you automatically unpack `dict_values` into a password and a user. *If* there were a third value (e.g., the schema also got included), you'd get an error: `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`. So you are more or less "lucky" in your working example.

Comment: I think the accepted answer in your linked question is too complicated; consider Amir's answer below, that does away with the whole `.values()` thing and makes things quite a bit simpler and easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

your first use of

```
password, user={k:v for k,v in secret.items() if k in pass_words+user_words}.values()
```

only works because by chance there are exactly two items in the dictionary, and by chance they are ordered in the correct order. i.e. if you changed your `secret` to

```
secret = {"user": "fjdklas",
          "password": "jdksal"}
```

it will not work anymore.

the better approach would be something like:

```
users_and_passwords = [v for k,v in secret.items() if k in pass_words+user_words]
passwords = [v for k,v in secret.items() if k in pass_words]
```

Answer (score 0):

values() called on a dict returns dict_values， in your code, there are exactly two elements in the result , at the left of the equal sign, three are two variables, auto unspack, if only one variable at the left of the equal sign ,it will not unspack

```
password, user=
```

your code is not rational， user_words = ['user', 'login', 'username', 'schema'], change user_words , run your code again, you will find error